# Display all parent records but only one record of child records of a parent record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have encountered an issue while writing a stored procedure for displaying some records of a table. The following code is to illustrate the issue.

```
declare @t table(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    ParentId int null,
    Item varchar(50)
)
-----------------------------------------------------------
insert into @t(ParentId,Item)
select null,'A' union all
select null,'A' union all
select 1,'B' union all
select 1,'B' union all
select null,'C' union all
select 2,'D' union all
select 2,'D'
```

The data after insertion in the table @t looks like this.

```
Id | ParentId | Item
---------------------
1     NULL       A
2     NULL       A
3      1         B
4      1         B
5     NULL       C
6      2         D
7      2         D
```

I want to select all records whose `ParentId` is null but select only the first record of those whose `ParenId` is not null.

Desired Result:

```
Id | ParentId | Item
---------------------
1     NULL       A
2     NULL       A
3      1         B
5     NULL       C
6      2         D
```

Any idea on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "only the first record of those" means ordered by `Id` you can use [rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) partitioned by `ParentId` and a `case statement` in the order by clause.

```
select T.Id, 
       T.ParentId,
       T.Item
from (
     select T.Id, 
            T.ParentId,
            T.Item,
            rank() over(partition by T.ParentId 
                        order by case when T.ParentID is not null 
                                   then T.Id 
                                   else null
                                 end ) as rn
     from @t as T
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1;
```

Comment: @AsrarAhmadEhsan is this not the result you want? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b61fa04a80a8697d3c605d61cc8b4c55